# Add auto-computed column in SQL

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I'm trying to add an auto-computed column in my SQL table, which should be easy enough. However, I keep getting an error message saying there's something wrong with the syntax beginning with the word "AS" in the input below:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD column_1 AS numerator / denominator;
```

The table "users" already exists, as do the columns "numerator" and "denominator". Any ideas?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: Sorry, I'm using MySQL

Comment: I don't think MySQL supports computed column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK. MySQL doesn't have support for built-in computed column like in `SQL Server`. With that, you have two options.

Add the column `column_1` using `ALTER` statement

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD column_1 ....;
```

Then `UPDATE` it like

```
UPDATE users SET column_1 = numerator/denominator;
```

(OR)

`CREATE A  VIEW` like below and then use it per your requirement

```
CREATE VIEW vw_computed
AS
SELECT col1,col2, numerator/denominator as column_1
FROM users
```

Select from view

```
select * from vw_computed
```

Answer (score 2):

We can't know for sure until you tell us what database system you are using, but most systems require parenthesis around your statement.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD column_1 AS (numerator / denominator);
```